# I Bad: VBA Confusion

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that works manually and with <kbd>Ctrl + I</kbd>, but when I put a button, the macro doesn't work.

```vb
Sub Duplicar()
'Updateby Extendoffice 20160922
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim VInSertNum As Variant
    xRow = 26
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While (Cells(xRow, "A") <> "")
        VInSertNum = Cells(xRow, "K")
        If ((VInSertNum > 1) And IsNumeric(VInSertNum)) Then
           Range(Cells(xRow, "A"), Cells(xRow, "K")).Copy
           Range(Cells(xRow + 1, "A"), Cells(xRow + VInSertNum - 1, "K")).Select
           Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
           xRow = xRow + VInSertNum - 1
        End If
        xRow = xRow + 1
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. *the Macro doesn't work* is not enough information. Is the button linked to the macro? Are macros enabled in the file? Also, last line of your code should be `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`

Comment: Hi. u are not referecing a sheet. are u putting the button on the sheet that u whant to duplicate?

Comment: @LuisCurado Lol, it was on the wrong sheet, thanks ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "put a button"?

Comment: @ZéMiguel If you follow the approach in the answer below it will always work no matter on which sheet you put the button.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I Bad"*?

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference in which worksheet your `Cells()` and `Range()` are. Otherwise, Excel cannot know that and starts guessing which worksheet you mean (and it fails guessing).

So set a variable to a worksheet

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

and use it to reference **all** `Cells()`, `Range()`, `Rows()`, etc. For example, like

```
Do While ws.Cells(xRow, "A").Value <> ""
```

Do this for all of them.

Also see *[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)*. Instead of using `.Select`, always use the range directly. For example, instead of:

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Insert
```

do directly

```
Range("A1").Insert
```

Finally your last line should be `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`, not `False`.